# Intellij how to fix "javadoc: error - invalid flag: --source-path"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

Whenever I try to generate a JavaDoc in Intellij (Tools -> Generate JavaDoc), leave the settings on default (output directory is my documents folder) I get the following error:

```
/home/John/apps/java/bin/javadoc -protected -splitindex -d /home/John/Dokumente @/tmp/javadoc_args
javadoc: error - invalid flag: --source-path
Usage: javadoc [options] [packagenames] [sourcefiles] [@files]
[...]
"javadoc" finished with exit code 1
```

My JavaDoc Code:

```
/**
 * @author John
 *
 * Dialog for test.java in Administration -> Anwendung
 * Set affected timespan, employee and testflag.
 * Confirm via Buttonpress
 *
 */
```

Comment: What is in `/tmp/javadoc_args`?  Have you included `--source-path` there?

Comment: @StephenC There is no "javadoc_args" in my tmp folder

Comment: What JDK version and vendor do you use in the project?

Comment: @StephenC Java Version 1.8.0_322

Answer (score 0):

Intellij IDEA runs Javadoc from your project SDK. If your project SDK is Java 8, the `--source-path` option is not supported, because this alternative spelling has been introduced with Java 9.

`/tmp/javadoc_args` is the options file generated by Intellij IDEA for your Javadoc run. In the "Run" dialog that lists the Javadoc command, the `@/tmp/javadoc_args` part should be a link that when clicked shows you the generated options in IDEA.

For me with Intellij IDEA 2021.2.3 Ultimate, the generated Javadoc options file does not use the `--source-path` option but lists each source file path separately. I think the reason for that is that I use a custom **Scope** for specifying the source files to document.

Answer (score 0):

1.SDK Java 8 is not supported the --source-path option
2.Need change project JDK
[first][1]
[second][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e39gC.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xa4i.png
3.OK,Tools -> Generate JavaDoc.

Comment: My image was not displayed ,ok, let me use text answer again, File -> Project Structure ->   SDK: select  new JDK.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).