# Javadoc cannot generate because of --source-path flag

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm working on a rather large project in java thus the need for javadocs.
I'm using java 1.8.0_332.
My problem is that when I try to generate the javadoc with Intelij Idea Community 2022.2.
It tries to use the --source-path flag when generating witch fails because it isn't yet defined in java 1.8.

Is there a way to force Idea to list the files separately if not is there a way to give javadoc the specified files manually. (yes I know at this point I should be using a build system to automate such things but I'm not the one making the calls on what I can use)

I've tried the methods in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73220285/intellij-how-to-fix-javadoc-error-invalid-flag-source-path) question to no avail.

As in the question mentioned above I've tried to generate the javadocs via the Tools -> Generate JavaDoc panel, witch returns this:

```java
1 error
javadoc: error - invalid flag: --source-path

"javadoc" finished with exit code 1
```

This error is due to me using java 1.8.0_332. I cannot change this in the main code compilation due to my spec regulations. Nor does the project have any build system. Again due to the spec this would be rather hard to push through. (I'm aware that a larger scale project should have one)

My second attempt was to use a custom scope where all my .java files are present.
This resulted in the same output as above.

I've ran out of elegant solutions at this point.

As the project is rather large and old code handed down to me I wouldn't want to manually list these .java files (though with scripting that could be a solution).

Are there any elegant solutions that I'm missing?

Comment: If this is an old large project, doesn't it use a build tool like Maven, ant, or Gradle? Can't that tool generate the Javadoc? If it has to be IntelliJ, can you install a modern JDK just for generating Javadoc? That said, it would be helpful to not link to another question but to include here in your question what you tried and how that failed. See [ask]

Comment: I hope that the edit helps clarify the situation. To answer you specifically, sadly the project does not have a build system. I've been nagging my team to add one but with no success so far. Thus the odd question. Regarding the IDE I have the choice of Eclipse also but that's being phased out. Ideally I'd like to write maintainable code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. At this point I'd probably just add a build script in your favorite tool. Or start with a shell script that runs Javadoc with the right arguments for you. If your teammates complain, don't check it in. At that point it's not a technical problem anymore but a team culture problem.